# Force the attr=title popup an on element

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way, I can force a element to show the "title" popup on hover of the element.

Or if not is there a way, I can configure what is the timeout before which it can show the title popup ?

Comment: There should never be a need to force it to show.

Comment: you can simply write `<p title="doesn't need any trigger">hover me</p>`..

Answer (score 2):

title is display on hover by default, you cannot change its behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> #### [3.2.3.2 The title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-title-attribute)
>
> The title attribute represents advisory information for the element, such as would be appropriate for a tooltip. On a link, this could be the title or a description of the target resource; on an image, it could be the image credit or a description of the image; on a paragraph, it could be a footnote or commentary on the text; on a citation, it could be further information about the source; and so forth. The value is text.

So the standard recommends that the advisory should be shown in an appropriate way. The HTML4 states, that *"values of the title attribute may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways. For instance, visual browsers frequently display the title as a "tool tip" (a short message that appears when the pointing device pauses over an object). Audio user agents may speak the title information in a similar context"*, see [7.4.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3).

However, if the user agent doesn't display the information, then you can't use the title attribute. But the default behavior in any graphical browser (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, ...) is exactly what the standard recommends: they show the title attribute's content as tool tip.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping I could somehow comunicate to the browser to show the tooltip quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Option one is that use you the "title" attribute as it is intended. This gives you little control. All you can do is set the content. You can't style or trigger it.

```
<div title="Can you see this tooltip?">My Content With Tooltip</div>
```

Option two is to use or build a plugin. There a loads for jQuery. Here is [one example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip).

Comment: yes, but was wondering if I could control the functionality of a popup. Like make it show quicker.

Comment: @PrakashRaman. To quote my post: "All you can do is set the content. You can't style or trigger it.". If you want to do anything outside of default behaviour, you need to use a custom tooltip component.