# HTML:"title" attribute style in td tag

Tags: html

Can someone tell me how to style a "title" attribute in td tag?

My code goes like:

```
 <td align="center" class="chaos" width="80%" >
  <a class="chaos" title="<%=trimtext%>">
<span class="chaos"><%=len(trimtext,50)%></span>
</td>
```

I can`t use jquery.
Suggest some answers.Thanks.

Comment: You need JavaScript or nested elements with CSS. You can't style any HTML attribute. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871417/force-the-attr-title-popup-an-on-element/12871452#12871452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you can't style the title popup that is provided natively by the browser. However, it is possible to refer to the title content in css using `attr`. For example:

```
td.chaos:hover::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}
```

That won't give you the delayed appearance that the native popup provides for free, but depending on your exact use case you might be able to come up with something that is useful (maybe by using transitions?).

Also, note that this styling doesn't eliminate the native popup, so you will end up with two popups.

Comment: MFoster: Thanks for the answer.I don`t see difference after adding this in my code.It comes default again.

Comment: As I said, the default popup will still be there. But you should see an additional element that you can style: http://jsfiddle.net/HVrgw/

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The little popup is native to the OS.

You can remove the title attr using javascript, then build a new div, absolultely position it based on the coordinates of the tag and replicate the effect though.

You don't have to use jQuery to do that, plain JS would be fine, but you will likely find it quicker in jQuery. (i.e. I'm thinking 2-5 lines of jQuery to do that).

If when you say "can't", you mean because you don't know how, invest some time in it – you will reap the benefits quickly!

If you say "can't" because your company doesn't allow it, just be glad you get paid per hour/day/month or whatever – it's nice of your company to want to finance development of alternatives to common libraries. Make sure you are able to either use the library you develop on your own, or open source it to ensure it's tested in many browsers.

Comment: Rich:Thanks for the suggestion.If you want me to use js,how would you do that?Sorry i`m week in such logics.

Comment: FYI: I was tempted to downvote this answer because of the irrelevant jQuery ad. There are valid reasons not to use jQuery. I did not because the first two paragraphs are still useful and relevant.

Comment: It's not so much an ad for jQuery as suggesting to someone who doesn't know much JS that it's a good place to start. Also, your answer is genius – I knew all the parts, but haven't thought to use it like that! Awesome! Might have to look up about CSS counters again, as those are the other thing I always ignore.