# Is it possible to show a title attribute on load using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

As the title states, I am wondering if it's possible to display a title attribute on page load. I am using Bootstrap 4, but the div below cannot be formatted with Bootstrap's ToolTip otherwise it compromises the language framework I've deployed.

```
div id="selectLanguageDropdown" class="localizationTool" title="You Can Select a Language Here !"> </div>
```

I tried:

```
 $(document).on('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#selectLanguageDropdown').attr('title','');
    , 3000);
 } );
```

Comment: "it's possible to display a title attribute on page load" do your page reloads? do you mean by selecting dropdown page reloads? and you want to show a loading screen I dont get you question would you please clarify more @Michael Maslova

Comment: @AlirezaMadad Absolutely. When the page loads, I'd like to show a tooltip type of message showing the user you can select a language here. it will be show then disappear after 3 seconds. I am just trying to find out if it's possible otherwise I will need to figure out how to implement Bootstrap's ToolTip. Does that make sense? The title attribute seems to be a good option..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force the attr=title popup an on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871417/force-the-attr-title-popup-an-on-element)

Comment: @ikiK No, I am trying to figure it if it's possible to show the title attr on page load for a total of 3 seconds. I don't want to use Bootstrap 4's ToolTip unless it's a last resort. It will interfere with my language framework.

Comment: The answer is No, its clearly stated in my link. You can not manipulate with this. You can make custom tool tip of data attribute and show that.

Comment: @ikiK damn... thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871417/force-the-attr-title-popup-an-on-element), you cannot change a title's behavior.

Comment: If there is a way to show the title popup on mouse move, there is a way to make it appear through code.

Comment: @Tomalak it’s all good. I figured out how to implement a tooltip without comprising a language translation framework.